# How to implement a function that returns boolean and changes one of its parameters?

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to define a function similar to the function

```
Physics.Raycast(
    origin: Vector3, 
    direction: Vector3, 
    hitInfo: RaycastHit, 
    distance: float = Mathf.Infinity, 
    layerMask: int = DefaultRaycastLayers
): bool;
```

Where it if it returns true it will also store information into one of its parameters, the "hitInfo" parameter which can then be accessed by whatever called the function, so how can I define a function that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're searching for something akin to `ref` in C#. UnityScript does not support anything like that. `Physics.Raycast` happens to do it because it actually calls a function that was defined in C# initially.

Your options are:

1. Do the same: write a function in C#, make sure it's compiled before your UnityScript, and call it from there.
2. Write an alternative solution, such as:

   ```
   class OperationResultWrapper
   {
         successful : bool;
         actualData: int;
   }

   //Note: YourOperation returns an instance of OperationResultWrapper
   var result = yourOperation(some parameters);
   if (result.successful)
   {
        //Do something with result.actualData
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks alot man :) That helps alot, and judging by this difference between js and C# I think I'll be switching to C# sooner or later, sounds like a huge option which I could highly benefit from hah, thanks again

Comment: its actually using "out" and not "ref" :)

Answer (score 0):

Alex' solution is nice but you should know there is a NATIVE way in UnityScript: You can use List/Collection objects like Hashtable, List, Dictionary ...

So if you put some values into a collection object and send it to a function that manipulates some list entries these entries remain changed after the use of the function outside the function too.

Example:

```
var list: List.<boolean> = new List.<boolean>();
list.Add(true);//0
list.Add(false);//1
list.Add(true);//2

if(isChanged(list)) {
    print( 'new list - 0:'+list[0]+' - 1:'+list[1]+' 2:'+list[2] ); 
    //-> new list - 0:false - 1:true 2:false
}

function isChanged( boolList: List.<boolean>) : boolean
{
    if(boolList!=null && boolList.Count==3) {
        boolList[0] = false;
        boolList[1] = true;
        boolList[2] = false;
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}
```